# jQuery run code after chunked $.each() is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the below code:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function () {

  var longArray = searchArray;   // assume this has 100 or more postalcodes init
  var shortArrays = [], i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = longArray.length; i < len; i += 100) {
      shortArrays.push(longArray.slice(i, i + 100));
  }

  // Now we iterate over shortArrays which is an array of arrays where each array has 100 or fewer
  // of the original postalcodes in it

  for (i = 0, len = shortArrays.length; i < len; i++) {

      // shortArrays[i] is an array of postalcodes of 100 or less
      $.each(shortArrays[i], function(index, value){
        setTimeout( function() {

          // Each parent gets its own searchToggle class
          $('.postcodes input[data-postcode*="' + value + '"]').parent().parent().addClass('searchToggle');
          // Each parent also gets a data filter attribute for ordering the results
          $('.postcodes input[data-postcode*="' + value + '"]').parent().parent().attr('data-filter' , index);
          // We display the items in the search array
          $('.postcodes input[data-postcode*="' + value + '"]').parent().parent().css('display', 'flex');
          $('.postcodes .searchToggle .postcode input[data-postcode*="' + value + '"]').parent().css('display', 'flex');

        }, 0 );
      })

  } // /for

  alert('Finished message');

});
```

I try to show an alert message(for debugging) once the $.each() is finished. Since this each goes through an array that could be 1000s of postal codes long I broke it up in chunks of 100. This to prevent the dreaded browser is unresponsive. This is all working fine but the alert fires immediately on click.

I have tried several things already:

1. I tried by using a count: `ABOVE THE EACH var count = 0; INSIDE THE EACH count++ if ( count == longArray.length ) { ALERT }` But this also fired the alert immediately???
2. I tried it by using an interval but that became a mess almost instantly.
3. I tried a couple of other SO answers but all of them resulted in the alert to fire immediately.

When looking through the jQuery docs and previous codes that I have written it should just run the code after the each is finished but in this case it does not.

Any idea on why this is and how I can fix it.

PS: This alert could be other codes! Like sorting the results or something else.

PS2: I can change all the js/jQuery you see but I cannot change any of the HTML selectors.

PS3: Thank you for thinking about this issue and especially for commenting/answering!

Comment: If I don't use the setTimeout then I get the page becomes unresponsive error in Chrome when for instance a user searches for a thousand postalcodes. I am testing right now by changing the timing on the timeout and I will test again without the timeout. I will let you know the result.

Comment: @JonUleis I first tried by adding a 100ms instead of the 0ms. This resulted in me receiving the alert 100ms later. Then I removed the timeout by commenting it and this did not made a difference at all. Alert came immediately. PS: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding another setTimeout.

So I replaced the alert (see Question) from

```js
alert(Finished message);
```

To

```js
setTimeout( function() {

  // As an example I used alert in my question and here in this answer. 
  // This can be offcourse anything else. I use it for instance to sort the results.
  alert(Finished message);

}, 0 );
```

This works for me, but it might not be the best way to deal with it. So I am still looking forward to what more experienced people think about the question or the answer.